# Graphql types, should they represent db fields?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

In Graphql, I have the following mutation:

```
activateUserAccount(token: String!): ActivateUserAccountResult!
```

the type is currently:

```
type ActivateUserAccountResult{
  id: Int
  activated_on: String
}
```

The problem with this is that the type ActivateUserAccountResult will most likely never get used by anything else. So I was wondering if i created a more generic UserAccount type as follows and returned that instead, can you think of why this might be bad?

```
activateUserAccount(token: String!): UserAccount !

type UserAccount {
  id: Int
  activated_on: String
  email: String
  ... other db fields here
}
```

The client would obviously still only request **id** and **activated_on** and ignore the other fields. The only downside i can think of is that you cant enforce activated_on by adding an exclamation mark (activated_on!).

Which is better practise? Better re-usability or more concise?

Comment: how many times `activateUserAccount` will be used? ... just include it in `updateUserAccount` ?

Comment: ActivateUserAccount will probably be used once. Sorry i dont understand what you mean by include it, could you give an example?

Comment: it's just a prop, does it deserve its own mutation? block/method called from updateUserAccount not enough?

Comment: The mutation needs an extra parameters (for ex. token) so are you suggesting: UpdateUserAccount(token) - and then detecting what the parameter is to know what to update in the account? For ex. If i receive token, then i need to update the "has_activated" field? I guess that could work but then i cant enforce the token being present, do you not see that being a problem?

Comment: There is no problem as you can just throw an error (missing `token`), difference will be in docs (no `!` char) ... but you're right, it should stay as separate mutation ... for other reason ... all other mutations requires being authed, login and activate not. Defining input and payload/result types for all mutations (even used once) is a kind of convention of API building, they are easier to change/update. You can reuse UserAccount as activate result - client **can** query for anything (it's a graphql!) or include it as `user` prop beside of boolean `result` (no `id` required, not cached).

Comment: "Defining input and payload/result types for all mutations (even used once) is a kind of convention of API building, they are easier to change/update." - Thanks, this is good to know :)